# Math without math class

Tags: code-golf

You receive an input with a number and a string with a space in the middle. The string tells you what you need to do with the number, it can be:

sqrt - square root of number

sqr - square of number

cube - cube of number

abs - absolute of number

round - rounded version of number

You need to output the final result of the calculation with whatever you have.
If your language doesn't have an input, you can hard-code that in.

**Rules:**

You can't use a math library, even if it is built-in.

You don't get a number or a result bigger than the highest possible one in your language.

Because of the vulnerability of the above rule, you can't use languages, which only support a 1 bit number. (1 and 0)

If your language doesn't support non-integer numbers, you need to output a rounded result.

**Test cases**

16 sqrt = 4

25 sqr = 625

3 cube = 27

-10 abs = 10

18.38 round = 18

Because this is a code-golf, the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Good luck!

Comment: `25 sqr = 625`?

Comment: can sqrt result in decimal values eg 5 sqrt?

Comment: Define a built-in math library

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Any functionality wich allows you to calculate something other than adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing. E.g. java and javascript Math class

Comment: @dev-null yes, 25*25 is 625

Comment: @Bálint Define "calculating something". If I use list indexing then does that count as calculation?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Ok, then any sort of functionality, wich allows you to calculate the squareroot/square/cube/absolute/roubded version of a number is prohibited.

Comment: Do we have to support imaginary square roots?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 no

Comment: @Bálint Javascript's `Math` is not a class.

Comment: It's not clear what *can* be used to calculate the requested operation. *any sort of functionality which allows you to calculate the square root of a number is prohibited* makes the challenge, by definition, impossible. You'd also have to clarify what counts as rounding.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>155</s> 153 bytes

```
{a=ToExpression@#,a a,a a a,c=a~Mod~1,a+Boole[c>=.5]-c,,,,If[Chop@a==0,0,a/Sign@a],If[a>0,(#+a/#)/2&~FixedPoint~1.,0]}[[Hash@#2~Mod~12]]&@@StringSplit@#&
```

Could probably be golfed further. Doesn't use "any sort of functionality, wich allows you to calculate the squareroot/square/cube/absolute/roubded version of a number."

Answer (score 1):

## Bash - <s>141 137</s> 132

```
t(){ for((;x*x!=$1;x++));do :;done;}
r(){ ((x=$1*$1));}
e(){ ((x=$1**3));}
s(){ x=${1#-};}
d(){ x=${1%.*};}
${2:${#2}-1} $1
echo $x
```

Run as

```
bash math.sh 16 sqrt
bash math.sh 25 sqr
bash math.sh 3 cube
bash math.sh -10 abs
bash math.sh 18.38 round
```

It strips the operation done to the last character, which is unique for each, then calls the appropriate function with the number

Comment: How does the square root work if the number is not a perfect square? Wouldn't it be an infinite loop? (Maybe replace != with < ? Even then the rounding seems wrong)

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 - 124 bytes

```
(a,b)=>eval('_=>'+'{for(c=1;c*c<a;c++);return c}_a*a_a*a*a_a<0?-a:a_a.toFixed()'.split`_`['tresd'.indexOf(b[b.length-1])])()
```

Square root only works for rounded numbers. Sqrt of 15 will result in 4, I hope this is allowed. Re-writing a fully functional square root function feels like overkill.

Explanation

```
(a,b)=> // anonymous function
    eval(
        '_=>' + // construct an anonymous function to eval
        '{for(c=1;c*c<a;c++);return c} // sqrt
        _ // seperator
        a*a // sqr
        _
        a*a*a // cube
        _
        a<0?-a:a // abs
        _
        a.toFixed()' // round
        .split`_` // create an array of functions
        [ // select the function to use
            'tresd'.indexOf(b[b.length-1]) // get index of input
        ]
    )() // end eval and call the returned function
```

Golfing tips are welcome

Test cases:

```js
f=
(a,b)=>eval('_=>'+'{for(c=1;c*c<a;c++);return c}_a*a_a*a*a_a<0?-a:a_a.toFixed()'.split`_`['tresd'.indexOf(b[b.length-1])])()

F=(a,b)=>document.body.innerHTML+='<pre>'+a+', '+b+':\n'+f(a,b)+'\n</pre>';

F(16,'sqrt')
F(25,'sqr')
F(3,'cube')
F(-10,'abs')
F(18.38,'round')
```

Comment: It is. As some of the people mentioned here, you can use the last letter of the input instead of the whole word, because it is unique for every type.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 153 bytes

```
S=str.split;x,f=S(raw_input())
exec'print '+dict(zip('tresd',S('[a for a in range(x)if a*a==x][0]|x*x|x**3|abs(x)|round(x)','|')))[f[-1]].replace('x',x)
```